# Assigning a file to a list

Tags: python, list, computer-science, custom-function

I have a program where I must store a file (included below) once the user specifies the name of the file. Then I must organize the contents of the file into a list and sift through the "survey responses" for certain keywords and calculations.
Here is the questions: [Survey Questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDjfm.png)

and here are the responses:
0|no|astrophysicist|yes
Off and on > 1 month|no|professor of physics|no
12|yes|professional soccer player| nope
3|yes|working at a software company|    yup
0|no|uhhh?|no
zero|no|being a coder|yes
6 months a Long time ago|yes|entrepreneur|      yes
none|nope|designer|
1|no|I don't know| yes
0|no|electrical engineer for a big company| no
3|no|computer engineer / scientist at microsoft| unsure
probably a few days|no|gooyie/microsoft/some bank|yes!

I have to create functions for each of the following choices which I am okay on, however I am unsure how to start the program by storing the file. Whether to make a dictionary, list of sublists with each individual response or some other method. I have attached the prompts for context here: [User choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKJch.png)

I need help starting the program with creating a main function that will prompt the user for the name of the file, which will always be "studentResponses2018f.txt" then, if the user has specified that file I will store all contents of the file to a "mainList". I have attached my current code as a picture and the actual code, I am at a loss for how to properly do this. Any help is appreciated.
current code:[currentCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZKYN.png)

```
    def main:
      mainList=[input("what is the file name?")]
          if "studentResponses2018f.txt" in mainList
              mainList=[[0|no|astrophysicist|yes],[Off and on > 1 month|no|professor of physics|no],[12|yes|professional soccer player| nope],[3|yes|working at a software company|    yup], #etc with all the file inputs
```

Comment: Bizarre behaviour: your file must be named "studentsResponses2018f.txt", and is prompted to the user to type the name, but if the name is not that one? The program ends?

Comment: There are other files available for every year the survey has been conducted so if desired I could include other file names in the conditionals and manually input their responses into if conditionals for if the user picks a different file year. However I'm opting out of including that because I am completing the bare bones program.

Answer (score 0):

Hard-coding the data inside the program is not a good idea. Write yourself "studentResponses2018f.txt" and other files somewhere, like this:

*studentResponses2018f.txt:*

> ```
> 0|no|astrophysicist| yes Off and on
> > 1 month|no|professor of physics|no
> 12|yes|professional soccer player| nope
> 3|yes|working at a software company| yup
> 0|no|uhhh?|no
> zero|no|being a coder|yes
> 6 months a Long time ago|yes|entrepreneur| yes
> none|nope|designer|
> 1|no|I don't know| yes
> 0|no|electrical engineer for a big company| no
> 3|no|computer engineer / scientist at microsoft| unsure
> probably a few days|no|gooyie/microsoft/some bank|yes!
> ```

then in your program read the file:

```
nameList = input("What is the filename?")
mainList = []
with open(nameList) as fn:
    mainList = fn.readlines()
```

Of course you have to implement a way to avoid the crash of the program when the user types a wrong filename.